# Javascript: Read text file into a matrix

Tags: javascript, file, matrix

I would like to read a text file with numbers and put them into a matrix using JavaScript

I know how to load, and read the file and even show the contents with the alert, but I have no idea how to put the contents into a matrix. I've been using the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

My idea is to get the numbers and use with Babylon.js so I can plot points into the canvas

Also another problem is that I want to skip a lot of lines and start to read from an exact word, is that even possible on JavaScript?

**EDIT:**

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        function readSingleFile(evt) {
            var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

            if (f) {
                var r = new FileReader();
                var contents = 'empty';
                r.onload = function(e) { 
                    contents = e.target.result;
                    alert( "File loaded:" + f.name + "\n"); 
                    alert(contents); 
                }
            r.readAsText(f);
            } else { 
                alert("Failed");
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
    } else {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser.');
    }
</script>
```

After reading the file, I want to put these numbers:

```
2.50000000000000E+0002 -2.00000000000000E+0002 2.00000000000000E+0001 3.09941176470588E+0002 -1.59941176470588E+0002 8.58823529411765E+0001 0.00000000000000E+0000 0.00000000000000E+0000 1.00000000000000E+0000
```

Into a matrix[x][9], where x is the number of lines on the file.

The first six numbers represents a coordinate (x, y, z) in the canvas, the last three represents the object color

**EDIT 2:**
The request from @NOBrien
The file is basically like this:

```
NUM_GRUPOS 1
[GRUPO]
TAM 64
[PONTOS]
ROTULO 1
 2.50000000000000E+0002 -2.00000000000000E+0002  2.00000000000000E+0001  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  1.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000
ROTULO 2
 3.54000000000000E+0002 -2.52000000000000E+0002  3.90000000000000E+0002  1.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000
... //A bunch of other numbers
[ARESTAS]
TAM 60
 2.50000000000000E+0002-2.00000000000000E+0002 2.00000000000000E+0001 3.09941176470588E+0002-1.59941176470588E+0002 8.58823529411765E+0001 0.00000000000000E+0000 0.00000000000000E+0000 1.00000000000000E+0000
```

I want to skip all these first lines and start reading from the ***[ARESTAS]*** keyword, I also need to get the number after the word ***TAM***

Is that even possible?

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far.

Comment: what is the matrix you speak of?

Comment: @dandavis The text file have a lot of numbers and i want to put them into a matrix [x][9], where x is the number of lines the text file have

Comment: @Ivaylo take a look at the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each row of data is on a new line and each data value is separated by one space:

Updated example will only add values that occur after the `keyword` row appears.  Only record rows that contain more than 2 fields.

```
var matrix = [];
var keyWord = '[ARESTAS]';
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    function readSingleFile(evt) {
        var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

        if (f) {
            var r = new FileReader();
            var contents = 'empty';
            r.onload = function(e) { 
                contents = e.target.result;
                var pastKey = false;
                contents.split('\n').forEach(function(line, i) {
                  if (pastKey) {
                    var vals = line.trim().split(' ');
                    if (vals.length > 2) {
                      matrix.push(vals);
                    }

                  }
                  if (line.trim() === keyWord) {
                    pastKey = true;
                  }

                })
            }
        r.readAsText(f);
        } else { 
            alert("Failed");
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser.');
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/nobrien/pen/ONodwO

Comment: That work really well, but in the case i have this same text file with a bunch of infos before the actual numbers, how can I skip those infos and start to read the file and put the numbers into the matrix from a determined keyword?

Comment: can you give a sample of what a row of data with the keyword would look like?

Comment: take a look at the EDIT2

Comment: Testing for the [complete file](http://pastebin.com/Fz8bjvu1) trying to read from the keywork [ARESTAS] or even TAM, won't work :(

Comment: So, could you say any row that only have numbers are the only ones that should be processed?

Comment: I could, but I want to read this kind of file, and they won't be the same everytime, that's why I want to read after the [ARESTAS] keyword

Comment: If there is anyway of counting the numbers of brackets chars I believe it would help, that's how [I did in C++](http://pastebin.com/AGzt7XXy)

Comment: OK, how about you read any lines that have multiple fields that occur after the [ARESTAS] keyword?  That would eliminate the TAM60 line, and also allow you to have mixed number/character rows that are still read.

Comment: No, mixed as in the row might contain both numbers and characters

Comment: I believe that would help a lot actually

Comment: OK, Codepen updated.  Hopefully that will do what you need!

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thanks a lot!